# Mosaico extension 2.4 beta installation?

Tags: mosaico

We have installed the latest of the mosaico extension (**2.4.1592820024**).

Either entering the *Mailings >> Mosaico templates* area or *Administer >> System status* results in an error message

```
Unrecognized Angular module
```

Or via civiCRM log files

```
[name] => crmMailing
[civi.tag] => deprecated

Unrecognized Angular module
```

The readme for beta-3 mentions both a validation step and the various template versions and an upgrade to verify them?

I've looked in */civicrm/admin/mosaico?reset=1* and don't see a verification or upgrade system? How do I install this extension and check that it is valid?

Comment: I have this same version of Mosaico installed on a couple of sites and the Angular Profiles extension is at 4.7.31-1.1.2.  Is that what you have?

Comment: I didn't have angular profiles. Just mosaico, org.civicrm.shoreditch-1.0.0-beta.1 and org.civicrm.flexmailer-1.1.1. Added angular profiles to the test system although it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I also have Mosaico 2.4.1592820024, Flexmailer 1.1.1, Angular Profiles 4.7.31-1.1.2, and Shoreditch 1.0.0-beta.1. I do recall having to clear cache to clear up funky layout issues after upgrading Shoreditch, but it otherwise seems fine.